# Autocomplete in Chrome Browser, not sure if its Mac OS or Chrome

Tags: mac, google-chrome, spellcheck, auto-complete

Every time I type "Th" in a text field within my Chrome browser, an autocomplete prompt of "Thanks" pops up. I've dug around and can't figure it if its a Chrome, plugin, or a macOS thing but its incredibly irritating. Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is called "[Text Replacements](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac)" and it's a function/feature of macOS.

This feature will work on any app that uses the [Cocoa interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)); so apps that use it like all native Apple Apps and 3rd party apps like Chrome will be able to use this functionality.  Apps that don't use Cocoa like Microsoft Word or Firefox won't be able to use Text Replacements.

To remove it (stop it from happening), open *System Preferences → Keyboard → Text* and remove the entry for "th". I just tried adding it, and it behaved exactly as you described. It even tried to intercept it as I typed it here until I removed the entry.

[image: Text Replacement Screen]

Comment: Hi Jer!  Welcome to Ask Different.  I made some substantial edits to your post so feel free to roll back or edit as necessary.  However, I wanted to add further detail about what the macOS function is that's causing the behavior as well as an image showing what you're describing.  It's all meant to enhance your (already correct) answer.  +1 and again...welcome!